# Combining .txt files into an .exe file

Tags: file, powershell

I have created a script in power shell, and have converted it into a .exe file. This .exe file requires some input files. 
How can I combine these input files with the .exe file. So that the tool can call the input file, read it, take actions. But the users cannot see or access those input files manually. Users can do changes to the file from the tool only.

Comment: Can you explain with more details what's the purpose of the data files? Why shouldn't the users be able to access them?

Comment: Its because i do not want anyone to delete those unknowingly.

Comment: With all due respect, are the users morons who actually *delete files for no reason*? Should this be the case, look up ACLs and user rights to prevent such a behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent unauthorized modifications, you need a method to sign the data files. This requires either public key encryption or home-brew hash+salt approach - which is *very* easy to implement in broken a way. What's more, if the program is being run on same computer than the users, a determined user might be able to reverse engineer the system anyway.

Comment: Initially i thought of adding a folder with all the input files. This tool will be used in different computers. Hence i am not able to hard code the path to input files in the script. So i want some other method to call these input files from the tool.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you'll get is to embed the text files as large string literals in your powershell script, and then re-convert to exe.

But this won't allow you *any* changes to the inputs at all. If you really want to block users from making changes, don't put the content on the user's machines. Make them pull and save it via web service.

Comment: Embedding data in Powershell script is [almost trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22758591/503046). I didn't suggest this approach; as you mention, it doesn't allow for data changes.