# Distributing powershell scripts with dll

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that references dll files and i would like to distribute this script to customers. How can i do this such that the customers don't have to worry installing/referencing correct dll files?

I reference the dll files from within the script in the following way:

```
Add-Type -Path <local path to dll>
```

I am looking for a way to either bundle these dll's along with the script , or some way for powershell to install the dll when it runs. The dll's i am interested in are available as following nuget packages:

1. [Sharepoint Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll/)
2. [Active Directory library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping Powershell script and files together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757851/wrapping-powershell-script-and-files-together)

Answer (score 1):

You could try copying the dll files to the directory the script is in and then use "$PSScriptRoot\Name.Of.File.dll". Zip the directory and distribute the Zip file.

Comment: This is how I always do it, in my opinion the most clean way to do this.

Comment: $PSScriptRoot gives no output (WS 2019, PSVersion: 5.1.17763.2268).